# Variance of sample when adding one value

Tags: statistics

After calculating the mean of a sample with $N-1$ values, $\overline{x}_{N-1}$, the addition of one value, $x_N$, will change the mean to $$\overline{x}_N = \frac{(N-1)\overline{x}_{N-1} + x_N}{N}$$

Is there a similar formula for calculating the variance when one value is added to the sample without knowing all sample values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) furnishes a sufficiently comprehensive treatment of this question that I see no need to provide further details on the topic.  It is a well-known algorithm in the literature.